# How to put an image's address on an object? FlatList

Tags: react-native

I need to place the address of some images in an object in the state for these images to render in FlatList. But I am facing an error. Does anyone know if this is possible?

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {View, Text, FlatList, Image, StyleSheet} from 'react-native';

export default class App extends Component{

  constructor(){
    super();

  this.state = {
    dados:[
      {nome:'Feijoada', preco: 29.99, img:'./img/batata.jpg'},
      {nome:'Batata Frita', preco: 14.99, img:'./img/feijoada.jpg'},
      {nome:'Strogonoff de frango', preco: 16.99, img:'./img/macarrao.jpg' },
      {nome:'Macarrão na chapa', preco: 9.99, img:'./img/batata.jpg'}    
    ]
  };

  }

  render(){
    return(
      <View>
        <FlatList data={this.state.dados} renderItem={({item})=>
          <View>
            <Text>{item.nome}</Text>
            <Text>{item.preco}</Text>
            <Image source={require(item.img)}/>
          </View>
        }/>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

[image]

Comment: read this: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/images; image' path can not be dynamic

Answer (score 1):

You have two options

- Use object with uri if you have the images stored in remote url then
- Use require in state to  get all images

Try this

**1.**

```
    import React, {Component} from 'react';
    import {View, Text, FlatList, Image, StyleSheet} from 'react-native';

    export default class App extends Component{

      constructor(){
        super();

      this.state = {
        dados:[
          {nome:'Feijoada', preco: 29.99, img:'./img/batata.jpg'},
          {nome:'Batata Frita', preco: 14.99, img:'./img/feijoada.jpg'},
          {nome:'Strogonoff de frango', preco: 16.99, img:'./img/macarrao.jpg' },
          {nome:'Macarrão na chapa', preco: 9.99, img:'./img/batata.jpg'}    
        ]
      };

      }

      render(){
        return(
          <View>
            <FlatList data={this.state.dados} renderItem={({item})=>
              <View>
                <Text>{item.nome}</Text>
                <Text>{item.preco}</Text>
                <Image source={{ uri: item.img }}/>
              </View>
            }/>
          </View>
        );
      }
    }
```

**2.**

```
    import React, {Component} from 'react';
    import {View, Text, FlatList, Image, StyleSheet} from 'react-native';

    export default class App extends Component{

      constructor(){
        super();

      this.state = {
        dados:[
          {nome:'Feijoada', preco: 29.99, img:require('./img/batata.jpg'},
          {nome:'Batata Frita', preco: 14.99, img:require('./img/feijoada.jpg')},
          {nome:'Strogonoff de frango', preco: 16.99, img:require('./img/macarrao.jpg') },
          {nome:'Macarrão na chapa', preco: 9.99, img:require('./img/batata.jpg')}    
        ]
      };

      }

      render(){
        return(
          <View>
            <FlatList data={this.state.dados} renderItem={({item})=>
              <View>
                <Text>{item.nome}</Text>
                <Text>{item.preco}</Text>
                <Image source={item.img}/>
              </View>
            }/>
          </View>
        );
      }
    }
```

Comment: is not working.
What is the difference between uri and require?

Comment: Device: (920:8812) Error: Module ./img/macarrao.jpg not declared as a System.registerDynamic dependency of module://App.js.js

Comment: which one ? 1 or 2 ?